# list.contains in salesforce not working with wrapper class

Tags: apex, list, contains

My wrapper class is as follow:

```
   public class FilterWrapper implements Comparable {
        public String label {get; set;}
        public String value {get; set;}


        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            FilterWrapper filterWrapper = (FilterWrapper) compareTo;
            if (label == filterWrapper.label) return 0;
            if (label > filterWrapper.label) return 1;
            return -1;        
        }

    }
```

I am using following code in apex.

resNameList  type : List

resName type :  FilterWrapper

```
if(!resNameList.contains(resName)) {                    
    resNameList.add(resName);
} else {
    Integer index = resNameList.indexOf(resName);
    resNameList.get(index).isShow = true;
}
```

I want to compare FilterWrapper instance based on label.

But

```
resNameList.contains(resName)
```

Always return false even for same label.

What is the issue in this ? How can we fix it ?

Comment: Its probably [equals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm) you need to implement.

Comment: yes, `Comparable` interface is used when there is a need to sort elements in `List`. Just wrong implemented  interface :)

Comment: Don't forget about `hashCode`! And it's not really an interface,  even though it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `List.contains` method works exactly like `Set.contains`. As mentioned in the comments, you need to implement `equals` and `hashCode` if you want to use custom types in this sort of comparison. Below is a simple test class to illustrate:

```
@IsTest
class Demo
{
    virtual class Foo
    {
        Integer x, y;
        Foo(Integer x, Integer y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
    class Bar extends Foo
    {
        Bar(Integer x, Integer y) { super(x, y); }
        public Boolean equals(Object instance)
        {
            Bar that = (Bar)instance;
            return this.x == that.x;
        }
        public Integer hashCode()
        {
            return x;
        }
    }

    @IsTest static void testFoo()
    {
        List<Foo> wrappers = new List<Foo> { new Foo(1, 2) };
        system.assertEquals(false, wrappers.contains(new Foo(1, 2)));
    }
    @IsTest static void testBar()
    {
        List<Bar> wrappers = new List<Bar> { new Bar(1, 2) };
        system.assertEquals(true, wrappers.contains(new Bar(1, 2)));
    }
}
```